# Choose city and redirect to url

Tags: javascript, redirect, selection

The url redirection is not working. I need to let users to select a city and go to the url page. What am I doing wrong?

```
window.location.href = 'http://' + city + '.example.com';
```

Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
var cityChosen = getCookie('citychosen');
if(cityChosen!=null && cityChosen!=''){
    var chosen = $('#choose option[value="'+cityChosen+'"]');
    chosen.attr('selected',true);
}
$("#choose").change(function(){
    var selected = $("#choose option:selected");
    var output = "";
    window.location.href = 'http://' + city + '.example.com';
    if(selected.val() != 0){
        setCookie('citychosen',selected.val(),365);
    }
    $("#output").removeClass().addClass(selected.val()).html(output);
});
});

function setCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}

function dropCookie(name) {
createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="choose">
    <option value="0">Select city</option> 
    <option value="amsterdam">Amsterdam</option> 
    <option value="newyork">New York</option> 
    <option value="london">London</option> 
    <option value="cardiff">Cardiff</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You see`window.location.href` here in this code is only a **property** that deals with the Url location. You need to set it to something in order to function.
The `window.location.href` is as same as var x="something" here.

So use the method `window.open()` which serves your purpose

```
window.open(window.location.href);
```

**Note:** There might be any mistake in spellings or syntax. i have just explained functionality. You can use varied parameters also. Have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: The window.open("http://www.google.com/"); is working but the cookie is not. And what about the rest of subdomains?

Comment: By the way i can find in your code there is "City" in  window.location.href = 'http://' + city + '.example.com'; where are you assigning city to?

Comment: <select id="choose">
    <option value="0">Select city</option> 
    <option value="amsterdam">Amsterdam</option> 
    <option value="newyork">New York</option> 
    <option value="london">London</option> 
    <option value="cardiff">Cardiff</option> 
</select>

Comment: @bagonyi is right. city variable is non-existent so I rename that to citychosen.

Answer (score 0):

First try to move window.location.href to the bottom of the $("#choose").change(function() {}); listener. Second, you are referencing a non-existent `city` variable, rename that to `cityChosen`.

Comment: It is basically working but so strange. The city selection picked the city randomly. If I select Amsterdam then Cardiff page is open. If I select London then Cardiff page is also open. And sometimes the page is unavailable.